# Easy way to send a "triggered" event to parent?

Tags: angular, events, event-handling

I have a component that should notifify the parent, if a button was clicked. I don't need to provide any data with it.

EventEmitter works like this:

`@Output() download: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();`

But what if I want just a void type or similar? `EventEmitter<Void>` doesn't exist and providing a value that I do not need is a bit against good coding style.

I basically just need to "tell the parent that the download button was clicked". Moving the button to the parent is no option, because that would mess up the layout.

Or is my approach wrong (often an indicator when you search for basic functionality without results)?

Comment: Send a boolean?

Comment: @AJT-82: If I don't need the boolean to process something, it's still obsolete.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What is going on in your parent? Do you mean you don't want to have even `(download)="doSomething($event)` in tag? What exactly do you want to happen when clicked? Should a function be called, some variable to be changed... or what should happen in parent?

Comment: @AJT_82: The parent takes a collection  and creates a json-file to download. Handling this collection is part of the parent's job, the child componend should not need to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `void` type:

```
@Output() download: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
```

You can find a more detailed answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464800/3776901