# What are the differences between EventEmitter<undefined> and EventEmitter<void>?

Tags: angular, typescript

Some times we can have a case when *generic variable* should be omitted.
Like this:

```
@Component( ... )
class MyComponent {

  @Output()
  public cancel = new EventEmitter<undefined>();

  private myFoo() {
    this.cancel.emit(); // no need to pass any value
  }
}
```

So, **the question**: Which is better way to define the EventEmitter type:
`EventEmitter<undefined>` or `EventEmitter<void>`.

- `void` is better because there is no an argument in `.emit()` call.
- `undefined` is better `.emit()` is the same `.emit(undefined)`

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 37):

According to the TypeScript docs, the `void` type accepts both `undefined` and `null` - therefore, the following code would be valid:

```
@Component( ... )
class MyComponent {

  @Output()
  public cancel = new EventEmitter<void>();

  private myFoo() {
    this.cancel.emit();
    this.cancel.emit(undefined);
    this.cancel.emit(null);
  }
}
```

Whereas with `EventEmitter<undefined>`, you would only be able to pass `undefined` or no argument, which is probably more correct in your case - that said, I can't see any major issues occurring just because you passed `null` to an emitter that you're not expecting a value from anyway, so I'd be tempted to choose `void` since it's the shorter option.